# Convert string to datetime in SQL Server 2012

Tags: t-sql

I have a below requirement.

I want to insert records into a table using a stored procedure with below parameters

```
CREATE TABLE Mytable (MyPassword VARCHAR(10),PasswordDateTime DateTime)
```

My stored procedure is as follows to insert data into the above table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPassword_Insert]
    -- Parameters
    @Password VARCHAR(200)
    ,@PasswordDateTime VARCHAR(20) 
AS

SELECT @PasswordDateTime = CAST(@PasswordDateTime AS DATETIME)
INSERT INTO Mytable
SELECT @Password,@PasswordDateTime
```

I get the value of @PasswordDatetime from stored procedure as '2020-01-13 12:19:43.02'

I am getting the `@PasswordDateTime` value as string from the stored procedure and I want to convert the value data type as Date-time as per table definition without changing the value format.I want to insert the value as it is but the data type is to be changed.

While I am trying to convert a `@PasswordDateTime` value into date-time format, I am getting `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string` error.

Please suggest how to convert this.

Comment: Why are you passing `@PasswordDateTime` to the stored procedure as string and not as `DateTime` to begin with?

Comment: You take a string, `@PasswordDateTime VARCHAR(20)`, `cast` it to a `datetime` (`CAST(@PasswordDateTime AS DATETIME)`) and then use [implicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#implicit-conversions) to convert it back to a string so that you can assign back to the original string variable. You want to store the `datetime` "without changing the value format", but a `datetime` doesn't _have_ a format, it is a binary value. It doesn't make sense in several ways.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

```
DECLARE @PasswordDateTime VARCHAR(50)='2015-12-02 20:40:37.8130000'
SELECT @PasswordDateTime =cast(@PasswordDateTime as datetime2(2))
SELECT @PasswordDateTime
```

Thanks